# TH not working properly in table

Tags: html, css

I have a table at this [url][1] which is being populated from PHP...now in this table I have 2 rows for TH tags...the top middle TH tag is getting wider with large values...here is the following code for the TH tags...

```
echo "<table style='font-size: 10pt;' width='100%'>";
echo "<tr>";
//echo "<td align='right'><b>SKU:</b></td>";
echo "<th align='left'><b>".$resultbe."</b></th";
echo "<th></th>";
echo "<th></th>";
//echo "<td align='right'><b>NAME:</b></td>";
echo "<th align='center'><b>".$resultnbe."</b></th>";
echo "<th></th>";
echo "<th></th>";
echo "<th></th>";
echo "<th align='right'><b>".$value."</b></th>";
//echo "<th></th>";
echo "</tr>";
```

I want to to reduce the gap between OUR PRICE, PRICE (NEW) columns in this table...can anyone please help me

Comment: The first row has nothing to do with the rest of the table. Separates it into multiple tables or try to accommodate using the colspan attribute.

Comment: @GabrielSNM...i have used colspan='2' in the Our Price TD...but the table design got distorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first row has nothing to do with the rest of the table. Separates it into multiple tables or try to accommodate using the colspan attribute.
Try this with the first row:

```
<tr>
    <th align="left">
        <b>SAMNX500Z1650</b>
    </th>
    <th align="center" colspan="4">
        <b>Samsung Nx500 Zwart + 16-50mm Powerzoom</b>
    </th>
    <th align="right">
        <b>8806086633727</b>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks...but with this design got distorted...please have a look into the url I have given

Comment: It is a table, you must to have the same number of cells in all rows or divided into different tables.

Comment: Ok, remove the empty cells at the other rows and change the colspan="5" to colspan="4" at the first row.